# Will a charged body generate current in this situation?

Tags: charge, electrons, electromagnetic-induction

Suppose we charge a body with negative charge. We then place it inside a Faraday shield that has openings in the form of vertical slits. A coil surrounds the shield. If we start rotating the Faraday shielding itself, will a current be produced in the coil?
[image: 1]

Comment: A Faraday shield will not stop the electric field from charge within it from coming out.  It only blocks electric field parallel to its surface.  If you imagine the electric field lines coming from the charge, they will go right through the Faraday shielding you drew.